# bootstrap-tagsinput instead of click on add , fields needs to be generte on enter

Tags: bootstrap-tags-input

I am using the bootstrap-tagsinput, when I click on enter fields needs to be added. instead of clicking on link_to_add specific button.

please guide

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `confirmKeys` values to:

```
$('input').tagsinput({
    confirmKeys: [13, 188]
});
```

whic are the `enter key` and `comma` by default.